# TensorFlow environment is not activated

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-16.04

I am having a problem with setting up tensorflow environment for good. I have installed all the required packages and Jupyter Notebook runs seamlessly without any problems. However there is one slight problem for which I could not figure out a solution so far. In fact, I am able to run tensorflow environment only if I excecute this command line `$source activate tensorflow` each time I would like to run `$jupyter notebook`. The following is where my tensorflow environment is created using anaconda :

```
$ ls /home/user/.conda/envs/
tensorflow
$ which jupyter
/home/user/.conda/envs/tensorflow/bin/jupyter
```

How could I please solve this issue once for good?

Comment: Sounds like `tensoflow` and `jupyter` are installed in different (virtual)environments.

Comment: @DušanMaďar I have edited the thread. Could you please have a look and tell me whether it is the case or not ?

Comment: `jupyter` is installed within a `virtualenv` named ` tensorflow` as `which jupyter` tells. In order to use tensorflow with `jupyter` you have to activate the environment.

Comment: @DušanMaďar Does it mean there is no solution for the given problem and I have to activate tensoflow environment each time I would like to use jupyter, is that what you saying?

Comment: You can create an alias, e.g. `alias tensorflow_jupyter='source activate tensorflow; jupyter notebook'` and put it to `~/.bash_aliases`. Otherwise yes, you have to run both commands.

Comment: Sounds a good idea! Thank you man.